# str_replace doesn't work with slash

Tags: php, regex, escaping, anchor, str-replace

For some reason `str_replace()` does not work with `/`. I am creating a function to accept a unique linking style in input and text area forms for a blog CMS that I am making. For instance, `[{http://brannondorsey.com}My Website]` will be translated to `<a href='http://brannondorsey.com'>My Website</a>` when passed through `make_link($string);`. Here is my code:

```
function make_link($input){

 $double = str_replace( '"', '&#34', $input);
 $single = str_replace("'", "&#39", $double);
 $bracket_erase = str_replace('[', "", $single);
 $link_open = str_replace('{', '<a href="', $bracket_erase);
 $link_close = str_replace("}", ">", $link_open);
 $link_value = str_replace(']', "</a>", $link_close);

 echo $link_value;
 }
```

Everything works correctly except for `]` is not replaced with `</a>`. If I remove the slash it will successfully replace `]` with `<a>`, however, as we all know, that does not properly close an anchor tag and therefor makes all html content between the `{`and the next closing anchor tag in my webpage a link.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's something else going on because this works fine: `echo str_replace(']', '</a>', ']');`

Comment: view source, your browser  wont show it as its a html tag, but the source will

Comment: @ExplosionPills I just tried `echo str_replace(']', '</a>', ']');` and it didn't echo anything. I even viewed the page source and no </a> tag was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I personally suggest the preg_replace answer of Marcus Recck below rather than mine here.**

its there just not seen because the browser wont show html, but you can use the below to see it, and\or use the browsers view source option

```
$link_close ="]";

$link_value = str_replace(']', "</a>", $link_close);

echo htmlspecialchars($link_value);//= &lt;/a&gt;

var_dump ($link_value); //=string(4) "" [invisible due to browser, but the 4 tells you its there]
```

the finial version of the OP's function:

```
function make_link($input){

 $double = str_replace( '"', '&#34', $input);
 $single = str_replace("'", "&#39", $double);
 $bracket_erase = str_replace('[', "", $single);
 $link_open = str_replace('{', '<a href="', $bracket_erase);
 $link_close = str_replace("}", '">', $link_open);
 $link_value = str_replace(']', "</a>", $link_close);

 return $link_value;
 }
echo htmlspecialchars(make_link('[{http://brannondorsey.com}My Website]'));
```

Comment: That is a great solution to the invisibly problem! But any idea why my `make_link()` function isn't working? Because now that we know it is actually replacing `]` than what would be going wrong?

Comment: @Brannon my fixed version: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pTwc5J just added the closing "

Comment: thanks for the vote, but i would do the preg_replace below, rather than  str_replace *6 my self

Answer (score 4):

You might want to go down the regular expression route for this.

```
function make_link($link){
    return preg_replace('/\[{(.*?)}(.*?)\]/i', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $link);
}
```

Comment: I actually haven't done anything with regular expressions before. What will `preg_replace('/\[{(.*?)}(.*?)\]/i', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', '[{http://brannondorsey.com}My Website]');` do?

Comment: It will return the link you want. `<a href="http://brannondorsey.com">My WebSite</a>` if you assign it to a variable. Just an alternative solution to your problem.

Comment: How would I apply this to the [{link}link_name] link insertion that I am creating? I think I understand how this will work for my specific case, but how will I get it to replace all instances of [{}] in a text area with the appropriate code?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your function.

Comment: Thanks so much! Will I still be able to turn single and double quotes into hexcodes if this regex is used? Or will I have to do something else?